# How do you change the value of a List[index].fieldname flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

How do you change the value of a `List[index].fieldname` flutter?

Comment: please, add some more details.

Answer (score 10):

```
class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
}

//assuming contacts is a List<Person>

contacts[index].firstName = 'Tony';
```

Comment: We also need to use `setState` in order to change the data.